# When did Greenwich begin to be pronounced as "Gren-ich"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, toponyms

I just read an [interesting question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/gmt-greenwich-mean-time-why-mean) on Greenwich Mean Time.

I'm interested to know when **Greenwich** received its peculiar pronunciation. Has it always been pronounced as "GREN-ich" (/ˈɡrɛnɪtʃ/), and is it just a simple contraction or something more?

I'm from Northern England and would say that GREN-ich is used nationally and globally, but I agree with Wikipedia that I've heard it pronounced GRIN-ich in London.

Comment: +1 Nice question... I didn't know that. Now it'll be a pain to avoid saying /ɡriːnwɪtʃ/ :D Even if actually I don't make that long vowel...

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/the-mysterious-unenunciated-w-in-the-wich-of-english-place-names

Answer (score 7):

*Greenwich* was originally *Grenevic* in Old English, and so has probably never been “Green-witch”.

Similarly, Norwich in Norfolk is pronounced “nor-itch”, and was originally spelt *Northwic*.

Comment: +1: N.B. In OE *Gipeswic* would have been pronounced *yippeswitch*.

Comment: @Robusto. Ipswitch wasn't a good example - I changed it

Comment: Thanks Martin. I find it interesting that it is written GREEN-wich in modern English. In our neck of the woods we have Northwich, Middlewich and Nantwich: all pronounced _something_-witch. (It's Ipswich of course not Ipswitch).

Comment: The Cheshire town is "Northwich" and is pronounced like that. Norwich is pronounced Nor-itch as you say. I wonder if the differences are regional?

Comment: @Dizzley - very likely the differences **are** regional: the town of Greenock in Scotland is pronounced with the long E sound ("ee") not short E ("eh"): TV newscasters frequently pronounce it wrongly, presumably influenced by Greenwich's short E.

Answer (score 7):

Two processes at work: pre-cluster shortening followed by wyn-dropping.

pre-cluster shortening:

> break ~ breakfast
>   green ~ Greenwich
>    goose ~ gosling
>   waist ~ waistcoat

wyn-dropping:

> historical one > an 
>  
>    husband > hussy 
>   inwards > innards
>   always > allus 
>  
>    will > 'll 
>    -wich, -wick > -ich, -ick

In his [Historical Wyn Dropping](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive24.html#blog240), Jack Windsor Lewis says

> Placenames abound throughout Britain ending -wich and -wick most of which retain their spellings with w but have long dropped their wyns eg Alnwick, Berwick, Bromwich, Chiswick, Greenwich, Harwich, Keswick, Norwich, Smethwick, Warwick, Woolwich. Some have restored their wyns if they ever lost them eg Droitwich, Hardwick, Ipswich, Nantwich, Sandwich and Lerwick. Surnames are more likely to have been re-spelt more phonetically as in the cases of Garrick and Crummle(s) the latter of which also exists as Cromwell.

Check his note on [Current Wyn Dropping](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive25.html#blog241).

Answer (score 2):

I guess I was taught wrong in school, what a shame. Green, as in the color two EE together (long Es) as sounded out in the color Green> wich should be sounded out just as it is spelled out,and should sound like the word witch(who can fly on a broom.) Thus you have the word (Greenwich) a woman colored green who can fly a broom ), and I thought they were all burned at the stake.Come to Greenwich , NY,12834 and they will gladly tell you how to pronounce this word .They even have a school insignia of a Green colored woman flying on a broom,(a witch) Green-witch

Comment: Greenwich, NY is pronounced differently from Greenwich, England. Just like Woburn, MA is pronounced different from Woburn, England, and Houston, TX is pronounced differently from Houston St. in Manhattan, and Theodore Roosevelt pronounced his name different from Franklin D. Roosevelt, and nobody outside of New Jersey knows how to pronounce the last name "Kean" properly.

Answer (score 2):

Greenwich in South London was originally (locally) pronounced "Grin idge" or "Grin itch". The pronunciation "Gren idge" is a recent pollution from (middle-class) newcomers to the area and one that also reflects a US inflection, e.g. Grenidge Village. Older local people do not like the new inflection imposed from 'without'.